# vb.net code block not being executed but showing no errors or warnings

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm having a weird issue with VB.net
I am trying to add a cefsharp control on my form, but can't seem to find any way to do it.

The problem is that the code is not executed at all, i am not getting any errors or warnings, yet no message box is showing.

I have tried adding a try/catch block, and to open a message box in case of exception.

The app is executed and a clean form is being shown, no messagebox or anything.

If i remove entierly the try/catch block, it's showing the first message box.

Thanks

```
Imports CefSharp
Imports CefSharp.WinForms

 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    MsgBox("start")
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    Try
        Dim x As WebView
        x = New WebView("http://www.google.ro", New BrowserSettings())
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("error")
    End Try
    msgbox("finished")
end sub
```

Comment: Do you have first chance exceptions enabled? Debug->Exceptions->Common Language Runtime -> check "Thrown". If not, turn them on and report back any exceptions you see when re-running the code.

Comment: I have turned them on, but no exceptions are showing when running the app.

Comment: You're declaring a local variable (`x`) and assigning it a value by creating the WebView, but the variable goes out of scope at `end sub` and therefore is discarded by garbage collection (it basically is thrown away). Declare the variable at a higher scope than the local sub.

Comment: see if this question/answer is applicable  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4934010/479512

Comment: The problem seemed to be happening because the references were not being copied to the debug folder. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you're trying to add a control to your form but there's no code there that actually does that.  You create a `WebView` so I expect that that's the control.  Like any other control, you have to actually add it to the form:

```
Me.Controls.Add(x)
```